# Invalid object name, reference to object which is already deleted

Tags: sql-server

I had `ProductAdmin` view which was renamed to `ProductDetail`. Now if I execute SQL database modification updates i get the error below. It seems somewhere the parmeter ProductAdmin still exist. I am new to SQL Server, how to solve this problem?

```
[208] Invalid object name 'dbo.ProductAdmin'.

The following SQL command caused the error:

EXEC sp_refreshview N'[dbo].[ProductDetail]'

The following messages were returned from the SQL Server:

[0] Altering [dbo].[Product]
[0] Refreshing [dbo].[OrderDetail]
[0] Refreshing [dbo].[UserDetail]
[0] Refreshing [dbo].[ProductDetail]
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do here by refreshing the view?